# Removing percentage of a priority queue in python

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

Is there a way to remove a certain percentage (let's say 20) of a queue once it reaches a certain size?

This question stems from a problem where a search algorithm is used that saves children nodes of the root parent board in a priority queue. There are so many different nodes to go through, that it takes more than 20 hours to find a solution. I would like to make rough cuts in the queue to shorten the number of nodes in order to find the solution faster, with the risk of throwing away the essential nodes that would lead to that goal.

Comment: Is there any restriction on which 20% that would be removed? For example, the highest-priority 20%? Those among the lowest priority? At random? Evenly distributed among the priorities? Etc. Also, which priority queue do you mean--`heapq` that is in the standard library, or another? Also, do you want this removal to be automatic, or could the supervising routine call for the removal when it wants?

Comment: The highest-priority 20% is a good rule to prevent removing the most vital nodes. I've changed my priorityqueue (imported from queue) to an heapq. And that works a lot faster. This will help my runtime. Evenly distributed or random should be tested to see what exactly works better, it's more trial and error with this project because the problems are so complex. The easiest way is to have an automatic removal after a certain threshold.

Comment: You could implement a [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), which would allow you to remove the lowest-priority 20%, keeping the most important items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you do not care which 20% of the items are to be removed, so I choose to remove those that disproportionally have the lowest priorities in the queue. Let's also assume that the priority queue is [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html) in Python's standard library. Finally, let's assume that this removal is to be done by the calling routines, whenever they choose to do so, rather than being done automatically by the priority queue structure itself.

The priority queue in `heapq` is a standard Python list with some functions added. If your priority queue is named `mypqueue` you can remove approximately 20% of the items, weighted toward those with lower priorities, with

```
mypqueue = mypqueue[:len(mypqueue) * 4 // 5]
```

or a slightly shorter alternative,

```
mypqueue[len(mypqueue) * 4 // 5:] = []
```

This simply truncates the list to 4/5ths of its length, removing the end of the list. This works because the properties of the heap are preserved in this truncation, so the if `mypqueue` was a heap-based priority queue, it still is.

This could be put into a function of its own, of course. You could also easily make a new class, based on Python's list, that would do this automatically when the queue's size reaches a certain number. I'll leave those to you.

Comment: An interesting solution, although the items removed won't necessarily be weighted towards the lowest-priority items. Removing 20%, you know that they're all leaf nodes, but there's a good chance that many of them will be fairly high-priority items. But you did qualify your answer and say, "assume that you do not care which 20%."